# Drools Agenda Group seems to be always run in parallel

Tags: java, drools, mvel

I have a simple DRools execercise project where my Java code is

```
public void runRules() {

    KnowledgeBase kbase = this.readKnowledgeBase();
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

    Isolate isolate = new Isolate(1l, ISOLATE_STATUS.INSERT.value(), 1);

    ksession.insert(isolate); /***/

    ksession.fireAllRules();
    ksession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup(Constants.DROOLS_AGENDA.DEVICE_AND_MANUAL.value()).setFocus();
    ksession.fireAllRules();
    ksession.dispose();

    System.out.println("Isolate status is "+isolate.getIsolateStatus());

}

private KnowledgeBase readKnowledgeBase() {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("org/lory/drools/trainer/business/resources/isolates.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);

    KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
    if (errors.size() > 0) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors) {
            sb.append(error);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(sb.toString());
    }

    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return kbase;
}

public enum ISOLATE_STATUS {
    INSERT(10),
    PRELIMINARY(30),
    ULTIMATE(60);

    private int isolateStatus;

    ISOLATE_STATUS(int isolateStatus) {
        this.isolateStatus = isolateStatus;
    }

    public int value() {
        return this.isolateStatus;
    }

    public static ISOLATE_STATUS lookupByValue(int value) {
        for(ISOLATE_STATUS isolateStatus : ISOLATE_STATUS.values()) {
            if(value == isolateStatus.value()) {
                return isolateStatus;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value "+value+" is not valid for enum ISOLATE_STATUS");
    }
}

public enum DROOLS_AGENDA {
    DEVICE("device"),
    MANUAL("manual"),
    DEVICE_AND_MANUAL("deviceAndManual");

    private String agendaType;

    DROOLS_AGENDA(String agendaType) {
        this.agendaType = agendaType;
    }

    public String value() {
        return this.agendaType;
    }
}
```

and where my MVel rules file is

```
package org.lory.drools.trainer.business.isolates

import org.lory.drools.trainer.facts.Isolate;
import org.lory.drools.trainer.commons.Constants;

rule "setIsolatePreliminary"
salience 10
no-loop true
dialect "mvel"

when
    $a : Isolate(isolateStatus == 10)
then
    $a.setIsolateStatus(Constants.ISOLATE_STATUS.PRELIMINARY.value());
    System.out.println("setIsolatePreliminary");
end

rule "setIsolateUltimate"
salience 9
agenda-group "deviceAndManual"
no-loop true
dialect "mvel"

when
    $a : Isolate()
    eval(isPreliminary($a))
then
    $a.setIsolateStatus(Constants.ISOLATE_STATUS.ULTIMATE.value());
    System.out.println("setIsolateUltimate");
end

function boolean isPreliminary(Isolate isolate) {
    boolean isPreliminary = isolate.getIsolateStatus() == Constants.ISOLATE_STATUS.PRELIMINARY.value();
    System.out.println("isolate is preliminary? "+isPreliminary+" ("+isolate.getIsolateStatus()+")");
    return isPreliminary;
}
```

But, at the end of each execution the output is always the same

```
isolate is preliminary? false (10)
setIsolatePreliminary
Isolate status is 30
```

While I would expect an output like `Isolate status is 30`.
Even if I run the code in debug mode and put a break point at line with /***/ and then go on step by step, I see that `isolate is preliminary? false (10)` line is printed at once.
Why does this happen?
As I was told, first rules with no agenda are evaluated and executed, and then the rules with `deviceAndManual` agenda. Instead, they seem to go always on paralles. I know that `salience` is not important as it is respected only in consequences functions application and not in conditions evaluations. Instead, I want `deviceAndManual` rules to be evaluated and applied only after the ones without agenda. Does it work like that? would anyone explain me please?

Comment: you need to call update or modify on an event if you want to call for a reevaluation of that event. Check here https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_fine_grained_property_change_listeners

Comment: Thank you for your kind response but I am afraid I cannot use that because we have a sort of "DRools widget window" which does not use `update()` in MVel generated rules. Can I use it in Java Consequence Functions? Is there any `import function` I can use?

Comment: Yes you can use check this http://blog.athico.com/2007/12/modify-block-for-java-dialect.html

Comment: Again thank you. I am afraid I did not explain well. The `modify` or `update` block in the example is defined inside the rule in the `when` block. So it is MVEL language. Instead, I would like to use it in Java Dialect Consequence Function...

Comment: Did you the answer of your question?\

Comment: No because I need that control on Java consequence functions, not in rules themselves

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirements. If you want to control the same from your program then call update function using the session object i.e kieSession.update(). It will be helpful if you try to elaborate more on your requirements.

Comment: I just wanted to be able to call update() from a function and from ny java code running DRools. I wanted to implement a Drools consequence function which calls update() before next agenda was evaluated. But I am afraid I misunderstood everything. I will try to do as you suggested calling update() from StatefulKnowledgeSession before next agenda on which fire all rules. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203954/discussion-between-prog-g-and-sagittariusa).